# Gatling HTTP Proxy

Tags: java, scala, proxy, load-testing, gatling

I am load testing a double sited HA application, whose each site is accessed by a proxy.
I need to attack both proxies equally through Gatling in a circular manner.

To do so, I am looking for a method to feed my proxies' IPs to the proxy http conf, but it seems Gatling doesn't parse feeders variables in that place !!!

```
val feeder = csv("prxyList.csv").circular
val scn = scenario("My Scenario")
  .feed(feeder)
  .exec(
    http("My Request")
    .proxy(Proxy(s"${proxyIP}", 8080))
}
```

Is there a way to feed the peoxy IP in a round robin manner for each execution ?Any Help is appreciated

Answer (score 1):

May be were overlooked but please see this ->

https://gatling.io/docs/current/cheat-sheet/  (Hover to Feeder ,,Cicular might fit your req )

https://gatling.io/docs/2.3/session/feeder/